# Gitlab 5.4 - cannot push (SocketError)

Tags: ruby, git, gitlab, bitnami

I got [GitLab](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq) 5.4 using [Bitnami Stack](http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab) 5.4.0-0

After creating user, login and adding key, when pushing to new repository

```
 git@gitlab.funshion.com:gitdemo1/gittest1.git: /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution (SocketError)
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `open'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `block in connect'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:55:in `timeout'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `connect'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in `do_start'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
    from /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:62:in `get'
    from /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:17:in `allowed?'
    from /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:60:in `validate_access'
    from /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:23:in `exec'
    from /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell:16:in `<main>'
```

UPDATE: 
Please help with starting GitLab server. We tried on 3 computers, no success.

UPDATE 2: gitlam.yml says relative_url_root is not supported, while Bitnami GitLab runs at server/gitlab/

```
# WARNING: This feature is no longer supported
```

UPDATE 3: A bit similar problem [Gitlab 5.4 push connection refused](http://answers.bitnami.com/questions/15195/gitlab-54-push-connection-refused) was solved by changing the default URL to the root http://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/BitNami_GitLab#How_to_change_the_default_URL_to_the_root.3f
However after executing all those steps, my GitLab is still running at /gitlab/ even after reboot.

accessing / , get message "Not Found: /" instead of default screen. So the transition is not full.

Comment: Copied to Bitnami Answers http://answers.bitnami.com/questions/15301/gitlab-54-canot-push-socketerror

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Server itself could not resolve the domain name. Solution is to add the domain in the /etc/hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1   gitlab.company.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Also check the redis configuration in the gitlab/config/resque.yml. Could be pointing to redis.example.com.